# Why scanf or fgetc does not work as expected

Tags: c, gcc

Following is my code and it is not stopping for first index and I wonder why ? Same is the result with `scanf`

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
  int n = 0, i = 0;
  char arr[10];
  printf("How many  characters do u want to enter ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  //printf("\n\t%d", n);
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {     
    printf("Enter %d character-->\n",i);
    char ch = fgetc(stdin);
    arr[i] = ch;
    //putchar(arr[i]);    
  }     
  i = 0;
  printf("You have entered characters are \n");
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {     
    printf("arr[%d] = %c\n", i, arr[i]);
  }     
  printf("\n");
}
```

When I run this code I get following

```
How many  characters do u want to enter 5
Enter 0 character-->
Enter 1 character-->
```

program does not wait for first character to input.

Comment: It should be `int main(void)`, not `void main()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an endline character on the input stream that is left there by `scanf("%d",&n)` and is read by the first `fgetc`

> Same is the result with scanf

Are you using `scanf` correctly? Try the following (don't miss the space before the `%c`):

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf("Enter %d character-->\n",i);
    scanf(" %c", &arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Terminals tend to be line-buffered, meaning that stream contents are accessible on a line-by-line basis.**

So, when fgetc starts reading from STDIN, it reads a character and leaves the newline character. So you should either use `scanf()` i.e. `scanf(" %c", &arr[i]);` as suggested by Cubbi. Or you need to discard that newline character otherwise. You may use this

```
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {     
    printf("Enter %d character-->\n",i);
    char ch = fgetc(stdin);    // newline is consumed here
    if(ch=='\n')
        ch = fgetc(stdin);         // you get the expected value
    arr[i] = ch;
    //putchar(arr[i]);    
  }
```

Comment: Better to verify a newline was gotten before throwing away.